# Can earthing cause black lines due to interference on a monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, interference

I have recently bought a new Acer monitor (maybe a month ago) and recently I am experiencing a thin black line on my screen, earlier there were multiple lines that appeared and disappeared and now it's just a single line that persists on the screen. It's not black so I don't think its dead pixels. My house does not have an earthing/grounding installed and I have some static on appliances during monsoon. Is the interference due to poor earthing causing problems? I don't think the issue is related to graphic drivers of anything in my laptop because I have tested for that.
Thank you.

Comment: If the cable from the monitor properly connects to the computer case (check that you have the correct cable, and possibly try another one), then I do not think the lack of house earth ground will cause an issue.

Comment: Btw, the io ports of my monitor are in a metal strip on the back of my monitor, and because of no grounding it has static present and it shocks me, can this he the source of the problem?

Comment: You may wish to consider grounding this set up. For ungrounded electrical sockets, the AC plug should have one blade wider than the other. It is possible for the AC to be plugged in backwards and the design of the monitor may require proper AC plug polarity. Grounding and 3-prong AC plugs is the best way to go

Comment: Update- I grounded the socket my setup is connected to and checked my laptop and hdmi cable with a different display and I do not get the lines on the other monitor. Plus the lines dont go even after grounding. Looks like the problem is in my monitor after all.

Comment: That is probably correct that it is a monitor problem. I did not say overtly at the beginning, but the implication was that if electrical connections are good, it would be the monitor.

Comment: Yes, it's good that the monitor still is in the warranty period. :)